# how to set a condition for arrays in where clause [BigQuery]

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I have an array in my table - something like this:

[image]

I need to take into account only rows where 'top_authors.author' = 'Caivi" and 'top_authors.total_score' = 3

I was trying to use unnest function but still I get the error "No matching signature for operator = for argument types: ARRAY, STRING. Supported signatures: ANY = ANY"

Could you help mi with that?

Comment: note: (just in case) `and 'top_authors.total_score' = 3` - this part of WHERE clause makes no much sense!

Comment: I know :) but In my case I have to write two conditions in "where" clause :) but ofc you're right :D in the above case this part of WHERE makes no sense. I couldnt find a better example online :)

Comment: don't look for examples online to include and reference in your question as this totally obfuscates your real use-case  - Instead just present your case as is so we will be able to help you!

Answer (score 3):

You can `unnest()` in a subquery in the `where` clause:

```
where exists (select 1
              from unnest(top_authors) ta
              where ta.author = 'Caivi' and ta.total_score = 3
             )
```

Or you can do this in the main query:

```
select . . . 
from t cross join
     unnest(top_authors) ta
where ta.author = 'Caivi' and ta.total_score = 3;
```

Assuming you don't have duplicates in the array, these should produce equivalent results.

Comment: I have just tried your solutions but for both cases I got the error message: "No matching signature for operator = for argument types: ARRAY<STRING>, STRING. Supported signatures: ANY = ANY at [6:22]"

Comment: @monika_w091 . . . Edit your question and provide sample data as a BigQuery CTE so we can see what the data looks really looks like.  This code should work based on the information you have provided.